# enum data type with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to create an enum using mongoid

```
class Vote
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :value, :type => Symbol # can be :aye, :nay, :abstain
  #field :group_type, :type => Integer

  belongs_to :user
  embedded_in :bill

end
```

I would be using this in a method in the User class:

```
  def vote_on(bill, value)
    bill.votes.create(:value => value, :user_id => self.id)
  end
```

I was thinking about setting a validation that limits to :aye, :nay, :abstain, but it seems there is probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its a better & clean way. I preferred symbols over strings when you have a known set of values to be processed.  Since mongo db doesn't have a symbol type it will be stored as a string.

And mongoid will take care of the conversion. Also symbols have slight advantage over strings. check out the [article](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings) for more info.